# I can't parse the right html code with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I try to parse price data from a website. But when I parse the html code, it is not the same as when I open it in a browser. I use python and the requests, beautiful soup and selenium modules. I have tried everything that is proposed in the web and in stack overflow but no luck.

An example url that I want to parse is https://www.skroutz.gr/s/19896259/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-8-Pro-64GB-Mineral-Grey.html. I try to find the element `<div>` with `class = 'price-content'` but I have no luck.

Can somebody explain to me why I can't find these elements? I read that probably selenium doesn't render the whole page but a part of it. Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: it might not be the case here, but technically websites can detect Selenium and serve slightly different pages. There are a lot of anecdotes about LinkedIn doing that

Comment: I just checked the Webpage under the mentioned URL. div elements with class= 'price-content' are populated when scroll action is performed on the page. And it is not a static content which soup can parse.

Comment: Any recommended actions? When I use selenium without a headless browser, I inspect the wep page that opens with selenium. When I click once, it shows html code that doesnt correspond with the part of the page where I clicked inspect. Then when I click for a second time, it shows the correct elements in the inspect code of Chrome.

Comment: I understood what you mean. I reloaded the page and the elements that contain the price aren't created at once. Is there any way to request the proper page?